# Where to put Thanks and +1 and say I did it without creating extra work?

Tags: discussion, comments, up-votes, thanks

Many times I want to tell the person who answers thanks and want them to know I up vote them. In the comment section it says not to so as a comment. Where should I say thanks ?

Comment: Generally voting information is not supposed to be revealed and that's why the error will be thrown if you try to say something like `+1` etc. Avoid them as much as possible but there are ways to bypass it (I will leave it to you to find them out). Thanks can be provided as a comment but if it is the only answer to your question then using the tick mark (accept) would be a better option.

Comment: Why do they need to know you upvoted? So they can upvote you back?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Nowhere.

If you like something, upvote it. That way the respondent gets an increase to their reputation, *and* posts with more votes float to the top of the page, thereby helping other people recognise that they are more popular (and therefore likely more correct) an answer.

Upvotes benefit everyone. `+1` comments benefit nobody.

I don't want to sift through dozens of `+1 great answer!!!` comments to find if there are actually some relevant comments on an answer. And nor does anyone else really.

Answer (score 11):

Telling someone you have voted (and how you have voted) is not necessary. If you want to give your appreciation, just vote for that post and possibly accept that specific answer.

We want to build a Q/A knowledge base here, and everything that distracts from that is removed. Discussions in comments, 'thanks', giving information about your votes, etc., is all unnecessary information that have no value for the overall information shared on the site.

You can point out a specific part of the answer that was helpful if you want to, that will emphasize it for future users which *is* helpful.